# Read current line

Tags: c#, forms, line, richtextbox

So I have searched for about 2 hours on the internet for a solution for this so I hope you can help me :) Really what I have tried to do is when the user press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the `RichTextBox` it adds a tab to the new line.
Example: Like in coding programs. Where you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and it auto aligns.

My code so far:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        //This is were the code should be
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't done winforms for a while, but I think you just need to cast "sender" into richtext box, and set the text to "sender.Text = sender.Text + "\t"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Appending '\t' escape sequence** works perfectly as the Enter already adds a new line.

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
{
     richTextBox1.AppendText("\t");

      // Edited After Comment
     var PrevLine = richTextBox2.Lines[richTextBox2.Lines.Count() - 1].ToString();
     var TabsCount = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(PrevLine, "\t").Count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude :D I'll mark this as the awnser but i have a sub question. Is there a way to read the line above to check of how many tabs it containes? Else thanks!

Comment: This won't work if you are editing some previous line, it will append the tab at the end, but if you press enter in the middle...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    int prevLine = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart) - 1;
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(richTextBox2.Lines[prevLine], "\s+");
    if (mc.Count > 0)
        richTextBox1.AppendText(mc[0].Value);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```